# How to use Alexa to turn a doorbell on/off (and determine state)?

Tags: smart-home, alexa

I'm relatively new to home automation, but experienced with electrical wiring and software development.  I'm looking for a solution that will allow me to tell Alexa to turn the doorbell on or off, AND allow me to query the current on/off state.  The smaller the better, so that I could wire it in before the doorbell transformer and keep it relatively hidden.  Though a solution that would work with low voltage (16VAC) would be great too.

I've seen a few WiFi-enabled switches out there, but I'm not sure which would be controllable by Alexa, nor is it clear if Alexa would be able to tell me the current state of the switch.

Has anyone done something similar?

Comment: Welcome to the site, Bill. What kind of doorbell do you have?

Comment: you could probably use an insteon device for this.

Answer (score 3):

As Graham suggests, it looks like Insteon have a [product](http://www.insteon.com/io-module) that will work (although maybe not an ideal fit). This is a mains-powered unit that implements low voltage switching and sensing. In order to interface to Alexa, you'd need the Instron hub too.

As an alternative, you could use 433 MHz modules and implement our own hub using a low-cost SBC (this may not save much in the long run, but could be an interesting project if you're so inclined). It is true that the majority of 433 MHz modules are one-way, mainly because of problems with battery drain at the remote end.

Answer (score 0):

IN 2024, almost any smart switch that has a clean contact or relay will do the job.  Unless its a Wifi unit, you will also need a hub of some description.  Once Alexa is integrated with it, you can turn it on or off and also interrogate the status of the switch.

As an example, I am using a Fibaro system integrated to Alexa.  I have gone a step further and Alexa will tell me hourly between 7pm and 11pm if any of the garage doors have been left open.